# MySQL, would like to get both a field and a count inside GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, count, group-concatenation

I can get a list of statuses that a tracking ticket *has had*, as well as the id of those statuses, as follows:

```
SELECT
t.id, t.name, GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(s.id, ':', s.name) ORDER BY s.id) AS 
all_statuses_history
FROM tracking t LEFT JOIN changelog c ON t.ID = c.tracking_id
LEFT JOIN statuses s ON c.changed_to = s.id
```

That will have duplicates (status can bounce around in the real world), so I change the `GROUP_CONCAT` with `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(s.id, ':', s.name) ORDER BY s.id) AS .. (etc)
```

That's better, but what I'd **REALLY** like is the id, status name, and *count* of instances, looking something like this:

```
1:Requested(1), 2:Pending(3), 3:On Hold(2), 4:Completed(1)
```

You'd read that as "the ticket bounced around between pending and on hold a bit and was finally completed".

I can't put `COUNT(*)` or apparently `GROUP BY` inside of a GROUP_CONCAT function.  Is it possible to get all of this information inside of a GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you must understand that you need 2 grouping levels - first will count status instances, and second will concat ticket statuses and counts. The first level may be performed in a subquery, if your server version is 5+, or it can be performed using window function (COUNT() OVER) or in WITH clause, if your server version is 8+. Specify your server version in a tag.

Comment: I added the version tag 5.5 (actually + but not 8 yet).  If you could provide an example, I couldn't figure out how to get a count besides a group by, but if I did a group by I'd split the rows and lose the ability to group_concat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a schema:

```
SELECT name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(status_id, ':', status_name, '(', status_cnt, ')')) AS all
FROM ( SELECT name, 
              status_id, 
              status_name, 
              COUNT(status_name) AS status_cnt
       FROM source_tableset
       GROUP BY name, -- first level GROUP BY and counting
                status_id, 
                status_name ) AS subquery
GROUP BY name -- second level GROUP BY and group concatenation
```